# WARN uninstall during attempted Yeoman removal

Tags: macos, node.js, installation, npm, yeoman

I installed yeoman recently and the installation is in my home directory and sloppy. I'm trying to completely remove it and reinstall in a new directory, but when I attempt to run

```
zach:~ zach$ npm remove yeoman -g
npm WARN uninstall not installed in /usr/local/lib/node_modules: "yeoman"
```

Does anyone have any advice how to fix this, and additionally how to make a clean install of npm and yeoman? Thanks